# Alpha Blending problems in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I am quite desperate to achieve desired alpha blending results in DirectX.
I am try to draw texture, and on it a color triangle strip.

Despite all my attempts it seems that color of the strip is affected by the color of the texture drawn before. Even if I set D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE to FALSE, I still see the color affected.

Here is how the image suppose to looks like (Rendered with openGL)

[image]

And here is what I get with directX rendering:

[image]

As you can see, the second image purple strip has yellow shade without any specific reason :( (The yellow rectangle is a texture, not a polygon).

Here is the setting I use in Engine initialization:

```
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_BLENDDIFFUSEALPHA);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
```

Those settings are the only settings that gave me correct Alpha Blending of textures, but I can in no way achieve correct blending of polygons. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.
In addition to Alpha Blending there is a Color Blending.
So DirectX merges color of the last texture with the last primitive.
In order to solve it we need to set:

```
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTSS_COLORARG1);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
```

before drawing the primitives - meaning only take color from primitive (Diffuse), and:

```
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTSS_COLORARG1);
m_pDirect3D_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
```

before drawing the texture - meaning only use texture colors.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but useful one!

I noticed a small detail, just to avoid some confusion: I think that the parameter to `SetTextureStageState` should be `D3DTOP_SELECTARG1` instead of `D3DTSS_COLORARG1` (same value anyway, so no big deal!).