# SDL2 load certain texture make SDL_RenderFillRect color weird

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I made a program that has two different states, one is for menu display-"Menu State", and the other state is for drawing some stuff-"Draw State".
But I came across a weird thing, if i load certain png for texture and copy them to renderer to display , then leave "Menu State" to enter "Draw State". The texture will somehow make the rectangle color not display properly (for example make green go dark).
In my code, switching to a new state(invoke MenuState::onExit()) will erase the texture map(map of texture smart pointer indexing with std::string) 
So the texutre loaded doesn't even exist in the "Drawing State".
 I couldn't figure out what went wrong. Here is some of my codes

```
void TextureManager::DrawPixel(int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer *pRenderer)
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = width;
    rect.h = height;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(pRenderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);//same color value
    SDL_RenderFillRect(pRenderer, &rect);
}

static bool TextureManagerLoadFile(std::string filename, std::string id)
{
    return TextureManager::Instance().Load(filename, id, Game::Instance().GetRenderer());
}

bool TextureManager::Load(std::string filename, std::string id, SDL_Renderer *pRenderer)
{
    if(m_textureMap.count(id) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    SDL_Surface *pTempSurface = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
    SDL_Texture *pTexutre = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pTempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);
    if(pTexutre != 0)
    {
        m_textureMap[id] = std::make_unique<textureData>(pTexutre, 0, 0);
        SDL_QueryTexture(pTexutre, NULL, NULL, &m_textureMap[id]->width, &m_textureMap[id]->height);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


void TextureManager::ClearFromTextureMap(std::string textureID)
{
    m_textureMap.erase(textureID);
}
```

```
bool MenuState::onEnter()
{
    if(!TextureManagerLoadFile("assets/Main menu/BTN PLAY.png", "play_button"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!TextureManagerLoadFile("assets/Main menu/BTN Exit.png", "exit_button"))
    //replace different png file here will also affect the outcome
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!TextureManagerLoadFile("assets/Main menu/BTN SETTINGS.png", "setting_button"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    int client_w,client_h;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(Game::Instance().GetClientWindow(),&client_w, &client_h);
    int playBtn_w = TextureManager::Instance().GetTextureWidth("play_button");
    int playBtn_h = TextureManager::Instance().GetTuextureHeight("play_button");
    int center_x = (client_w - playBtn_w) / 2;
    int center_y = (client_h - playBtn_h) / 2;
    ParamsLoader pPlayParams(center_x, center_y, playBtn_w, playBtn_h, "play_button");

    int settingBtn_w = TextureManager::Instance().GetTextureWidth("setting_button");
    int settingBtn_h = TextureManager::Instance().GetTuextureHeight("setting_button");
    ParamsLoader pSettingParams(center_x , center_y + (playBtn_h + settingBtn_h) / 2, settingBtn_w, settingBtn_h, "setting_button");

    int exitBtn_w = TextureManager::Instance().GetTextureWidth("exit_button");
    int exitBtn_h = TextureManager::Instance().GetTuextureHeight("exit_button");
    ParamsLoader pExitParams(10, 10, exitBtn_w, exitBtn_h, "exit_button");

    m_gameObjects.push_back(std::make_shared<MenuUIObject>(&pPlayParams, s_menuToPlay));
    m_gameObjects.push_back(std::make_shared<MenuUIObject>(&pSettingParams, s_menuToPlay));
    m_gameObjects.push_back(std::make_shared<MenuUIObject>(&pExitParams, s_menuExit));
    //change order of the 3 line code above
    //or replace different png for exit button, will make the rectangle color different

    std::cout << "Entering Menu State" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool MenuState::onExit()
{
    for(auto i : m_gameObjects)
    {
       i->Clean();
    }
    m_gameObjects.clear();
    TextureManager::Instance().ClearFromTextureMap("play_button");
    TextureManager::Instance().ClearFromTextureMap("exit_button");
    TextureManager::Instance().ClearFromTextureMap("setting_button");
    std::cout << "Exiting Menu State" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

```
void Game::Render()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer);
    m_pGameStateMachine->Render();
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer);
}
```

[Menu State Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ3lw.png)
[Correct Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EBXc.png)
[Wrong Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewiap.png)

**edit** :Also, I found out that this weird phenomenon only happens when the renderer was created with 'SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED' flag and -1 or 0 driver index, i.e `SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, 1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);` or `SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);`works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been plagued by this very same issue. The link provided by ekodes is how I resolved it, as order of operations had no effect for me.

I was able to pull the d3d9Device via [SDL_RenderGetD3D9Device()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderGetD3D9Device), then [SetTextureStageState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-settexturestagestate) as described in ekodes d3d blending [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107121/alpha-blending-problems-in-directx9/15110345#15110345).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I got a vibrant green color when trying to render a light gray.

The combination of the parameters that are fixing the issue for you pertain to the driver to be used. `-1` selects the first driver that meets the criteria, int this case it needs to be accelerated.

Using [`SDL_GetRendererInfo`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRendererInfo) I was able to see this happens when using the "direct3d" driver.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107121/alpha-blending-problems-in-directx9/15110345#15110345) talking about blending in direct3d.

> I figured it out eventually. In addition to Alpha Blending there is a Color Blending. So DirectX merges color of the last texture with the last primitive.

The question does provide a fix for this in DirectX, however I'm not sure how to apply that it in regards to SDL. I also have not been able to find a solution for this problem in SDL.

I was drawing Green text with SDL_ttf, which uses a texture. Then drawing a gray rectangle for another component elsewhere on the screen.

What's strange is it doesn't seem to happen all the time. However, mine seems to predominantly happen with SDL_ttf. At first I thought it may be a byproduct of `TTF_RenderText_Blended` however, it happens with the other ones as well. It also does not appear to be affected by the blend mode of the Texture generated by those functions

So in my case, **I was able to change the order of the operations to get the correct color.**

**Alternatively, using the OpenGL driver appeared to fix this as well.** Similar to what you mentioned. (This was driver index 1 for me)

I'm not sure this classifies as an "Answer" but hopefully it helps someone out or points them in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, looks like we are having the same issue. Changing the order of operations works for me too, though it is troublesome to determine the right order. I wonder if the issue has something to do with the SDL compatibility on the hardware side.